# Excel Vba Macro Code to search column variables

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on an excel sheet which creates report.

I allow the user to input the month (as an integer: for ex: 1 for Jan, 2 for Fev and so on).

I am able to collect it in a variable say x.

Now, I want to use this value of x to search all the date entered for the particular month and create the report. I am trying to use month() function. How ever I am unable to compare it with x. x is defined as an integer variable.

What should I use to be able to solve this.?

```
Function mois_de_date()


    mois = InputBox("Choisissez le mois (Entrer la valeur Numérique)!!! (1 pour Janvier, 2 pour Fév .... )", "Titre")

 If mois > 12 & mois <= 0 Then
    If mois = 1 Then
    MsgBox "Janvier"
    End If
    If mois = 2 Then
    MsgBox "Février"
    End If
    If mois = 3 Then
    MsgBox "Mars"
    End If
    If mois = 4 Then
    MsgBox "Avril"
    End If
    If mois = 5 Then
    MsgBox "Mai"
    End If
    If mois = 6 Then
    MsgBox "Juin"
    End If
    If mois = 7 Then
    MsgBox "Juillet"
    End If
    If mois = 8 Then
    MsgBox "Août"
    End If
    If mois = 9 Then
    MsgBox "Septembre"
    End If
    If mois = 10 Then
    MsgBox "Octobre"
    End If
    If mois = 11 Then
    MsgBox "Novembre"
    End If
    If mois = 12 Then
    MsgBox "Décembre"
    End If
 End If
```

' Inside main sub

```
mois_de_date

If month(Date_de_survenance) = mois Then
    Date_to_search = Date_de_survenance
    MsgBox "Correct"
End If
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: what is the data type of `Date_de_survenance`?

Comment: I have used Date variable for Date_de_survenance.

Answer (score 0):

Say we have dates in column A.  The following will hide rows not matching a specific month:

```
Sub durall()
    Dim x As Integer, r As Range
    x = 5
    Dim DateRange As Range
    Set DateRange = Intersect(Range("A:A"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
    For Each r In DateRange
        If Month(r.Value) <> x Then
            r.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

You can then copy the visible rows to use in your report.

Comment: If you have viewed my code, then i would just like to know why If month(Date_de_survenance) = mois Then
    Date_to_search = Date_de_survenance
this section is not working, rest all, I will manage.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the data types. `MONTH` returns a value (integer), but the `InputBox` function returns a string. You can see the problem when you run the following code (with `1-Jan-2012` in cell `A1`, all the way to `1-Dec-2012` in cell `A12`.

```
Sub test()
  Dim x
  Dim c As Range
  x = InputBox("what month?", "month to use", "1")
  MsgBox "x is " & x

  monthValue = Val(x)

  For Each c In Range("A1", "A12").Cells
    If Month(c.Value) = x Then
      MsgBox "the matching cell is in " & c.Address
    End If
    If Month(c.Value) = monthValue Then
      MsgBox "I can match the value at " & c.Address
    End If
  Next c
End Sub
```

When you run this you will see that the message displayed is "I can match the value at..." rather than "the matching cell is in ...". In other words - `Month(c.Value)` is not equal to anything returned by `InputBox`, and you have to do the conversion explicitly (using `Val(x)` in the example above).

Comment: Nope. In the Function mois_de_date, If I declare a variable j as integer and assign it value as 1 and then compare it with if mois = j then MsgBox "Janvier". it still works, So I don't think that is the solution of my problem. Thank you anyway. I am still looking for answers.

Comment: So you are saying that the comparing of `mois` with `MONTH(Date_de_survenance)` is working? Please give us the shortest complete piece of code that doesn't do what you want / expect. Any chance that it's a language thing (your date is given in French but the spreadsheet expects English dates)?

Comment: Floris, Thank you for your help. I have fixed it. The variable mois i was using inside a function and obviously its value outsid the function was not same. So it failed. fixed it. thank you

Comment: I had assumed you had declared it outside of your function (i.e. that it was a global variable). This is the peril of posting only a part of your code - and not enough to reproduce the problem. Glad it's solved now.

Comment: Yeah. I am sorry, forgot basic rules of programming.
Now I have a quick question, does VBA allows me to make Array of Date variable..?